# How do I password protect a page of posts on Wordpress?

Tags: password

I have several pages on my site, and I want to password protect a page which displays the latest posts. Simply going to the admin panel and setting "Visibility: Password protected" isn't doing anything so... Any help?

I am using Wordpress 4.3.1 on a local machine, if that's any use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "setting "Visibility: Password protected" isn't doing anything"? It is a built-in feature in WordPress that works for everyone else. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness... I mean the page still shows all its contents without asking for a password. It's as if I had set "Public" on the admin panel for the page.

Comment: In that case, it must be something broken in your WP installation. You should try to fix it instead of asking how to password protect a page because that feature already exists in WP. Deactivate all plugins and switch to a default theme. Check if password protect works correctly and then activate the plugins one by one and switch to your theme; this way you can isolate the plugin/theme where the problem come from.

Comment: I've disabled all plugins, switched to default twentyfifteen theme and that still happens.

Comment: The only things I've changed in the default WP install is that I've added a CSS and JS file to the header to add my own changes, but that's it. Definitely no PHP.

Comment: I think I know what it happening. When you create a page and assign it to "Page for posts" in Settings->Reading, it is not considered a page anymore but an archive. That is why standard password protection doesn't work. You will need to build the latest posts page at your own, for example using a page template and/or `pre_get_posts` action.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for that - I'll go ahead and give that a try. I can accept your answer if you wish to put it in answer form?

Comment: You have to edit all the post one by one. In edit section you have to change **visibility setting** there here is the full [guideline](http://sharmablogs.com/password-protect-posts-in-wordpress/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a page and assign it to "Page for post" in Settings->Reading, it is not considered a page anymore but an archive. Taht is why standard password protection doesn't work. You will need to build the latest posts page at your own, for example using a page template and/or `pre_get_posts` action.

Answer (score 0):

Password-protection is an in-built feature of WordPress, in case you didn't know. When creating a page, you simply click “Edit” next to Visibility in the Publish box on the right. Choose “Password protected” and set the password as you choose.

Below is screenshot for It. It is also available on page too. screenshot taken of post.

[image]

Comment: I did that, and when I checked the page (using either Preview Changes or navigating straight to the page) it still shows all the page contents.

Comment: try logging out and accessing the page again